# How to copy a file and all the directories that comform his path

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

Is there an easy way to copy an specific file nested in an already nested directory creating an structure of directories nested in the same way its file path (in linux)?

for instance;

```
copy_command A/B/C/a.txt OTHER_DIR
```

would create

```
OTHER_DIR/A/B/C/a.txt
```

creating the directory structure A/B/C into OTHER_DIR and copying the file a.txt on his corresponding dir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU `cp`

```
cp --parents -- A/B/C/a.txt OTHER_DIR
```

Answer (score 0):

The `${var_name%pattern}` syntax removes `pattern` from the variable's value. With that in mind:

```
file="A/B/C/a.txt"
mkdir -p "OTHER_DIR/${file%/*}"
cp "$file" "OTHER_DIR/${file%/*}/"
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
mkdir -p OTHER_DIR/A/B/C
cp A/B/C/a.txt OTHER_DIR/A/B/C/
```